# Jenkins : cannot exectute docker commands from jenkins

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-docker

I cannot execute any docker commands from jenkins and receieving below error,

```
+ sudo docker pull ubuntu
Using default tag: latest
Error response from daemon: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/library/ubuntu/manifests/latest: unauthorized: incorrect username or password
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

Things i tried

1 ) jenkins user is part of the docker group on the Jenkins master

```
ubuntu@ip-10-20-10-106:/tmp$ groups jenkins
   jenkins : jenkins sudo docker
```

2 ) docker version

```
ubuntu@ip-10-20-10-106:/tmp$ docker --version
Docker version 19.03.6, build 369ce74a3c
```

how to solve this issue ?

Comment: From the error, it seem the docker registry requires authentication. Are you doing that?

Comment: how to check it.. i can run docker commands without sudo access

Comment: You mean you can pull images from the docker registry? If yes, then under your home dir, check for a hidden dir with the name `.docker`. If your docker registry requires authentication, then there will be a file inside `.docker` dir which contains the credential. When you run `docker login` and provide your credential, it creates this dir structure in your home dir. Similar action will be required for Jenkins.

Comment: i give jenkins user sudo access .. does that is enough

Comment: sudo access is actually not required. If you will run `ps -ef | grep -i jenkins`, you will find out the `id` with which Jenkins process is running. Once you know that, just switch to that user and then run `docker login` command. This will create the necessary dir structure inside that user's home dir. Then you can try running the Jenkins job.

Comment: Other way (the preferred way) is to create a docker credential in Jenkins as explained here: https://medium.com/@gustavo.guss/jenkins-building-docker-image-and-sending-to-registry-64b84ea45ee9

Comment: i try to login with  jenkins user but its asking for password.. i didnt have any password..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211465/discussion-between-technext-and-karamzov).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the error, it seems the docker registry requires authentication. If it's working for you from the command line and not working when you switched to Jenkins user on the host box, then it means that Jenkins need to authenticate itself when connecting to the docker registry. Just `sudo` to Jenkins user and then run `docker login` command. After you successfully authenticate, you should be good to go.